# Latex Tables and section are in wrong order

Tags: tables

So i have this latex code in my project (Tables.tex which is included in main.tex)
When i compile this the tables and sections are in wrong order
[image]

```
\subsection{Tabulka uzivatel}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka uzivatel}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & PK \\
nazev & varchar(60) & ano & \\
heslo & varchar(60) & ano & \\
email & varchar(120) & ano & unikátní \\
skupina\_id & int & ano & \\
cas\_vytvoreni & timestamp & ano & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka dodavatel}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka dodavatel}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
dodavatel\_id & int & ano & PK \\
identifikacni\_cislo & int & ano & \\
nazev & varchar(125) & ano & \\
ulice & varchar(200) & ano & \\
cislo\_popisne & varchar(20) & ano & \\
mesto & varchar(100) & ano & \\
postovni\_smerovaci\_cislo & varchar(50) & ano & \\
danove\_identifikacni\_cislo & varchar(12) & ne & \\
je\_aktivni & boolean & ne & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka dph\_sazba}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka dph\_sazba}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
dph\_sazba\_id & int & ano & PK \\
nazev & varchar(100) & ano & \\
hodnota & float & ano & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka odberatel}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka odberatel}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
odberatel\_id & int & ano & PK \\
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & FK (uzivatel) \\
nazev & varchar(125) & ano & \\
ulice & varchar(200) & ano & \\
cislo\_popisne & varchar(20) & ano & \\
danove\_identifikacni\_cislo & varchar(12) & ne & \\
mesto & varchar(100) & ano & \\
postovni\_smerovaci\_cislo & varchar(100) & ano & \\
identifikacni\_cislo & int & ne & unikátní \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka pokladni\_doklad}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka pokladni\_doklad}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
id\_pokladni\_doklad & int & ano & PK \\
evidencni\_cislo & int & ano & unikátní \\
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & FK (uzivatel) \\
castka & float & ano & \\
prijato\_od & text & ano & \\
ucel & text & ano & \\
datum\_vystaveni & date & ano & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka polozka}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka polozka}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
polozka\_id & int & ano & PK \\
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & FK (uzivatel) \\
nazev & varchar(200) & ano & \\
vychozi\_cena & float & ano & \\
dph\_sazba\_id & int & ano & FK (dph\_sazba) \\
jednotka\_id & int & ano & FK (jednotka) \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka faktura}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka faktura}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
faktura\_id & int & ano & PK \\
datum\_vytvoreni & timestamp & ano & \\
datum\_aktualizace & timestamp & ne & \\
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & FK (uzivatel) \\
evidencni\_cislo & int & ano & unikátní \\
datum\_vystaveni & date & ano & \\
datum\_zdanitelneho\_plneni & date & ano & \\
datum\_splatnosti & date & ano & \\
forma\_uhrady\_id & int & ano & FK (forma\_uhrady) \\
odberatel\_id & int & ano & FK (odberatel) \\
stav\_faktury\_id & int & ano & FK (stav\_faktury) \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka forma\_uhrady}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka forma\_uhrady}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost \\
\hline
forma\_uhrady\_id & int & ano \\
nazev & varchar(30) & ano \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka jednotka}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka jednotka}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost \\
\hline
jednotka\_id & int & ano \\
nazev & varchar(50) & ano \\
zkratka & varchar(5) & ano \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka polozky\_faktur}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka polozky\_faktur}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
polozky\_faktur\_id & int & ano & PK \\
faktura\_id & int & ano & FK (faktura) \\
polozka\_id & int & ano & FK (polozka) \\
cena & float & ne & \\
pocet & int & ano & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka sablona}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka sablona}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
sablona\_id & int & ano & PK \\
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & \\
datum\_vytvoreni & timestamp & ano & \\
datum\_aktualizace & timestamp & ne & \\
nazev & varchar(150) & & \\
html & text & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka skupina}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka skupina}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost \\
\hline
skupina\_id & int & ano \\
nazev & varchar(50) & ano \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\subsection{Tabulka stav\_faktury}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Tabulka stav\_faktury}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost \\
\hline
stav\_faktury\_id & int & ano \\
nazev & varchar(50) & ano \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome! `table` is a float environment i.e. it is designed to float to an appropriate position, which is not necessarily (or usually) where it is entered in the text. You do not really need `\subsection` here unless you also have some ordinary text to put in there. Otherwise, the `\caption`s already provide headers for the tables. Alternatively, if you don't want them to move, don't use a `table` environment. Just use e.g. `center`. Then the table won't move, but you may get poor page breaks. If you want more specific help, please complete your code so we can compile it.

Comment: Hello. I'm not so sure of the intention of your code (something similar to cfr comment). If the problem is floating objects passing to the next section, or subsection in your example, then you might want to try `\FloatBarrier` from [placeins](https://ctan.org/pkg/placeins) package before any subsection.

Answer (score 1):

As @cfr has already pointed out in a comment, it's not a good idea to use `table` environments if their contents are never supposed to "float" (in the LaTeX-specific sense of the word). Just use `center` envrionments instead. Moreover, I'd omit the captions, as they merely repeat what's in the subsection-level headers -- and are thus redundant.

Depending on your document's page dimensions -- about which you've provided no information so far -- it may be necessary to insert some `\newpage` instructions to keep the subsection-level headers and their associated `center` environments on a common page. (It's not necessary for the code shown below.)

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}   % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtx}         % or some other suitable font package
\usepackage[slovak]{babel} % is 'slovak' correct?


\begin{document}

\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example
\setcounter{section}{1}

\subsection{Tabulka uzivatel}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & PK \\
nazev & varchar(60) & ano & \\
heslo & varchar(60) & ano & \\
email & varchar(120) & ano & unikátní \\
skupina\_id & int & ano & \\
cas\_vytvoreni & timestamp & ano & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka dodavatel}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
dodavatel\_id & int & ano & PK \\
identifikacni\_cislo & int & ano & \\
nazev & varchar(125) & ano & \\
ulice & varchar(200) & ano & \\
cislo\_popisne & varchar(20) & ano & \\
mesto & varchar(100) & ano & \\
postovni\_smerovaci\_cislo & varchar(50) & ano & \\
danove\_identifikacni\_cislo & varchar(12) & ne & \\
je\_aktivni & boolean & ne & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka dph\_sazba}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
dph\_sazba\_id & int & ano & PK \\
nazev & varchar(100) & ano & \\
hodnota & float & ano & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka odberatel}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
odberatel\_id & int & ano & PK \\
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & FK (uzivatel) \\
nazev & varchar(125) & ano & \\
ulice & varchar(200) & ano & \\
cislo\_popisne & varchar(20) & ano & \\
danove\_identifikacni\_cislo & varchar(12) & ne & \\
mesto & varchar(100) & ano & \\
postovni\_smerovaci\_cislo & varchar(100) & ano & \\
identifikacni\_cislo & int & ne & unikátní \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka pokladni\_doklad}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
id\_pokladni\_doklad & int & ano & PK \\
evidencni\_cislo & int & ano & unikátní \\
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & FK (uzivatel) \\
castka & float & ano & \\
prijato\_od & text & ano & \\
ucel & text & ano & \\
datum\_vystaveni & date & ano & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka polozka}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
polozka\_id & int & ano & PK \\
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & FK (uzivatel) \\
nazev & varchar(200) & ano & \\
vychozi\_cena & float & ano & \\
dph\_sazba\_id & int & ano & FK (dph\_sazba) \\
jednotka\_id & int & ano & FK (jednotka) \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka faktura}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
faktura\_id & int & ano & PK \\
datum\_vytvoreni & timestamp & ano & \\
datum\_aktualizace & timestamp & ne & \\
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & FK (uzivatel) \\
evidencni\_cislo & int & ano & unikátní \\
datum\_vystaveni & date & ano & \\
datum\_zdanitelneho\_plneni & date & ano & \\
datum\_splatnosti & date & ano & \\
forma\_uhrady\_id & int & ano & FK (forma\_uhrady) \\
odberatel\_id & int & ano & FK (odberatel) \\
stav\_faktury\_id & int & ano & FK (stav\_faktury) \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka forma\_uhrady}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost \\
\hline
forma\_uhrady\_id & int & ano \\
nazev & varchar(30) & ano \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka jednotka}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost \\
\hline
jednotka\_id & int & ano \\
nazev & varchar(50) & ano \\
zkratka & varchar(5) & ano \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka polozky\_faktur}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
polozky\_faktur\_id & int & ano & PK \\
faktura\_id & int & ano & FK (faktura) \\
polozka\_id & int & ano & FK (polozka) \\
cena & float & ne & \\
pocet & int & ano & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka sablona}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost & Klíč \\
\hline
sablona\_id & int & ano & PK \\
uzivatel\_id & int & ano & \\
datum\_vytvoreni & timestamp & ano & \\
datum\_aktualizace & timestamp & ne & \\
nazev & varchar(150) & & \\
html & text & & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka skupina}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost \\
\hline
skupina\_id & int & ano \\
nazev & varchar(50) & ano \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}


\subsection{Tabulka stav\_faktury}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
\hline
Název atributu & Datový typ & Povinnost \\
\hline
stav\_faktury\_id & int & ano \\
nazev & varchar(50) & ano \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```